# why does the init-method of a custom nib-based table cell not get called

Tags: objective-c, nib

I have a nib-based table view cell which I created in Interface builder. I set the class of the table view cell to `FooTableViewCell` which extends from `UITableViewCell`.

In `FooTableViewCell` I override the init method like this:

```
-(id)init{

    if ((self = [super init])){
      // My init code here
    }
    return self;
}
```

I now expected that my gets called, when it is being instantiated. However the table view gets displayed but the method is never called.

I could work around this but I would like to fully understand it and for me it's not clear how an object can come to live without the `init` method being called.

Comment: if you load your cell from nib file the way you posted you don't need 'cell = [[StationAndTwoProgramsCell alloc] init]; ' line - as created with alloc/init cell will get overwritten anyway in the next line 'cell = ...' and that will also result in memory leak.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When being unarchived initialization goes through a slightly different path.

Instead of `-(id)init` being called `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder` will be called. At this point outlets aren't hooked up, if you need access to the outlets you can override `-(void)awakeFromNib` which will be called after the object has been hooked up.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Been trying to find a way of 'defaulting' all of my custom cells background colours from a custom superclass. This worked great!

Answer (score 7):

When object is being loaded from nib file then its -awakeFromNib method is called - you can put your initialisation code there:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
   // Init code
}
```