# Need some clarity on NIB file objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, interface-builder, nib

I have a `MainViewController` class set up with a simple nib. On the nib i have only these few objects. I have set the popoverViewController's file owner to the MainViewController.
[image]

I have set the popoverViewController class to my `PVController` class so that i can put buttons/code/labels etc.
[image]

The Popover works fine, but somethings are is puzzling me which i need help to understand.

1. That newly created PVController class has an init method that is **never** called when the popover is loaded. Yet the popover still works? If i put break points in the -(IBAction) buttons however, they are called when i click the buttons for them. But the init is never called. If I however, go to the file owner (MainViewController) and do --> PVController *pv = [[PVController alloc] init], only then it is called. So my first question is, will there be any problems if i do **not** alloc/init an IBOutlet in FileOwner, since it seems to work without it (altho the PVController's init method isnt called)? And why isnt it called?
2. If i *did* decide to create that IBOutlet in FileOwner for the Popover View Controller's referencing outlet, do i make it as strong? or weak? My noobish instincts tells me weak because it is already owned by the NIB, but when i put weak, I get a yellow error next to the init of the IBOutlet saying message

[image]

Comment: Read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html (because the object is unarchived from the NIB file...)

Comment: Related: [why does the init-method of a custom nib-based table cell not get called](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6942152/335858).

Comment: You should also read the [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/), which explains, among other things, the correct ownership policies to use with nib objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my first question is, will there be any problems if i do not alloc/init an IBOutlet in FileOwner

NO, there will not be any problem. Infact IBOutlets are never alloc+init manually.

Comment: thanks. Ok. so one thing, if i needed iVars initialized in the init method, since it is not being called because it is unarchived from the nib, then i have to go with approach #2? i.e. alloc/and init from the files owner?

Comment: And last part, would the IBOutlet be strong? or should it be weak

Comment: Make it weak since the popover is already retained by it's superview.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri seems the answer is `Strong` and not weak.  I asked the question again here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256056/should-an-outlet-to-a-view-controller-class-be-weak-or-stong-osx-app

Comment: It's saying that top level outlets that aren't retained by anything should be strong, while subviews should be weak, since they're retained by superviews.