# Should an outlet to a view controller class be weak or stong? OSX app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib, nspopover

Here's what i did.

1. Make a clean OSX project.
2. went to main.xib and dragged a popover controller.  This created 2 visible objects on on interface builder.
3. I went to the appDelegate.h file and did

   `-@Property (**assign**) IBOutlet NSViewController *popVC;
4. Then i went to the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method and did

   popVC = [[NSViewController alloc] init];

Result: I get the following error message:

[image]

Shouldnt objects on a nib be weak since it is already owned by the nib?

Comment: I always go for `strong`, I never found any situation where I need `weak`, and yes for delegates i use `unsafe_unretained`.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya  Why not `weak` for delegates?

Comment: @Abizern: I guess `weak` will `nil` the the pointer when deallocated.

Comment: Which is what you want for delegates. `unsafe_unretained` isn't necessary if you are using full ARC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Outlets to view controllers should be `strong`. The NIB doesn't own the objects, its just an archive. Outlets to views should usually be `weak` but that's because the view is retained by its superview (the superview is usually retained by its view controller).

---

As an aside, you shouldn't be doing:

```
popVC = [[NSViewController alloc] init];
```

Because `popVC` is being unarchived, created and set when the NIB is loaded. By creating and setting an instance yourself you're throwing the NIB version away. This applies to all outlets - the purpose of an outlet I'd to be filled in when a NIB is loaded.

Comment: @Wain I might have chosen this as correct a bit too soon. One last explanation please? This behavior happens not just with NSViewController objects on the IB outlet. It happens with ALL of them. Now im really confused. Could i zip my sample project and send you so you see what i mean?

Comment: If you'd like to put the code on GitHub or upload somewhere and add a link here i`ll take a look.

Comment: Outlets to top level items in a xib should be strong, Any subviews of those top level objects can be added as weak IBOutlets as they are strongly referenced by the top level items.

Comment: @Wain Abizern filled in the missing parts. Thanks guys.